# How to play video as audio in Media Element UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, mediaelement

Currently I'm playing youtube videos with MediaElement but I want to hide the video and leave the audio playback and the transport controls only.

The MediaElement shows only the controls when an mp3 file is being played but when it's a video format it keeps showing the video as well. So is there a way to make it work as if the file was in audio format ?

I looked everywhere if there is a way but unfortunatelly didn't find anything so I decided to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

> How to play video as audio in Media Element UWP?

I'm afraid there is no such api could play the audio only for video file. But we have a workaround is use `MediaComposition` translate video to audio, then set the stream to `MediaElement` for more code please refer to the following. And if you do want to this native feature for `MediaElement` please feel free post your requirement with windows feed back hub app.

```
 var videoFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("hello.mp4");

 // Create a MediaClip from the video file and apply our video effect
 MediaClip clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(videoFile);

 // Create a MediaComposition object that will allow us to generate a stream source
 MediaComposition compositor = new MediaComposition();
 compositor.Clips.Add(clip);


 var profile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp3(AudioEncodingQuality.Medium);
 var mediaStream = compositor.GenerateMediaStreamSource(profile);

 MyMedia.SetMediaStreamSource(mediaStream);
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly this won't work because the video I'm playing is from the web. Maybe the only way is to play the music on a hidden media player and create custom player controls.

Comment: Yep, create custom player controls is better `way` to implement audio play only, you could make a switch to display or hide a image cover on the MediaElement